# Can't get javascript to show the data in my HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a website as a project for a class, and I am new to `javascript` and I need some help on that.

The evaluation on the project consists on having tables, and making them display information, then make a form (in this case "registering" on the website), and then make a little `javascript` using `.document.getElementById("")`. Finally, when pressing a submit button, the info you just placed in the form should be displayed down below.

So this is what I have. (I will only show the last table which contains the submit button, because it is a large html)

```
<table class="tablasub" border="0" width="600px" height="70px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="registrarocancelar">

            <input class="registrarse" id="btn-entrar0" type="submit" name="btn-entrar0" value="Registrarse" >

            <input class="cancelarsub" type="submit" name="cancelarsub" value="Cancelar" formaction="main.html">

            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<center><span class="" id="div_abajo1"></span></center>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
```

And in the js file I have this.

```
    document.getElementById("btn-entrar0").addEventListener("click", funcionBoton);

function funcionBoton() {
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre")
    var correo = document.getElementById("correo")

    document.getElementById("div_abajo1").innerHTML = '<table><tr><td>Muchas gracias' +nombre+', te has registrado con el correo'+correo+'. Gracias por preferirnos.</td></tr></table>' 
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who helped or commented.

Comment: Change your element "spam" to "span" for starters.

Comment: @Daniel Changed it, and it doesn't display anything yet.

Comment: Where are 'nombre' and 'correo' fields?

Comment: You need to have a database for that , Or else you can just store the values into an array and the loop it out to the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who helped.

After a few hours of discussing with some programmers at my university and thinking about it non-stop I got to a fix.

Basically in the `var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre")` code, I was missing `.value;`. I also moved the `<form>` tag to the top of the form, if anyone would like to see the whole code, just ask for it and I will send it to you.

So at the end the code looked like this. (Notice I changed some ID's but either way with old ID's it would've worked)

The HTML CODE

```
<table class="tablasub" border="0" width="600px" height="70px">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input class="registrarse" id="btn-entrar0" type="submit" name="btn-entrar0" value="Registrarse" >

         <input class="cancelarsub" type="submit" name="cancelarsub" value="Cancelar" formaction="main.html">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <center><spam class="" id="div_abajo1"></spam></center>
            <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    </header>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The Java Code

```
document.getElementById("btn-entrar0").addEventListener("click", funcionBoton);

function funcionBoton() {
    var nombre = document.getElementById("inputnombre").value;
    var correo = document.getElementById("inputcorreo").value;


    console.log(nombre)
    document.getElementById("div_abajo1").innerHTML = 'Muchas gracias'+nombre+', te has registrado con el correo'+correo+'. Gracias por preferirnos.'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and is doing what you want it to do.

However, when you click on `Registrarse` button, the form will get submitted and brings you to another page as a result.

You can prevent that from happening by doing `onsubmit="return false"` on your `<form>`.

This will get the form to do nothing and just `return false` when the form is submitted.

```js
document.getElementById("btn-entrar0").addEventListener("click", funcionBoton);

function funcionBoton() {
    var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre")
    var correo = document.getElementById("correo")

    document.getElementById("div_abajo1").innerHTML = '<table><tr><td>Muchas gracias' +nombre+', te has registrado con el correo'+correo+'. Gracias por preferirnos.</td></tr></table>'
}
```

```html
<table class="tablasub" border="0" width="600px" height="70px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="registrarocancelar" onsubmit="return false">

            <input class="registrarse" id="btn-entrar0" type="submit" name="btn-entrar0" value="Registrarse" >

            <input class="cancelarsub" type="submit" name="cancelarsub" value="Cancelar" formaction="main.html">

            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<center><span class="" id="div_abajo1"></span></center>
```

Comment: I'll  give this a go, and notify you on what happens. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line to your form tag to prevent redirect on submit.  `onsubmit="return false"`